# What is the DSDT Table? If I change it, will I be unable to apply BIOS updates in the future?

Tags: windows-vista, bios

[Eddie says](http://eddietse.blogspot.com/2008/03/patching-dsdt-table-for-8510p-to-reduce.html) I can change the DSDT table on my HP laptop, using the ASL Compiler.

I did this and it seemed to work.
Should I be worried about future BIOS updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found DSDT defined [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/ACPI-HOWTO/dsdt.html). This is defined in [ACPI](http://www.acpi.info/) as a way for the BIOS to tell the OS how to access & configure the features that the system provides such as thermal control and configuration. The method used overrides the tables provided by the manufacturer's BIOS. It is intended for debugging and development. Future BIOS updates may be overridden as well. Proceed with caution. Keep an eye on your system's temperature readings for awhile to make sure slowing down the fan doesn't have any unintended consequences.

Comment: Thank you, perfect. Just what I needed.  I am not slowing the fan, too much.  Your advice is good - I watched the temp with the CPUID hardware monitor tool called HWMonitor.exe - it seems fine.